# A parameter with type return value is not the first parameter, or there are more than one parameter of type return value

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I'm trying to execute a SP with an input parameter and the SP is going to return a value where I need to capture it in a SSIS variable...

I used SQL script task to achieve this, problem is I don't know how to order the the parameter name/ parameter size column...

Below is the screenshot of the SQL script task .
[image]

Can someone explain me how to use "Parameter name" and "parameter size" in Script task. This the code I'm using:

```
exec pr_procname ?
```

I'm using the OLEDB Driver

Comment: What does the SQL Look like? What kind of driver? (ADO.Net or OLEDB?) How are you returning the value in your SP? There are about four different ways to do it. The way you have configured is for a return parameter

Comment: SQL- "exec pr_procname ?".... Driver OLEDB....Return value from SP has return statements like "Return @validcount" returning a variable from SP..... Let me know if you need any further info

Comment: Now that we know what form your SP is we can check the first google hit that comes back: http://bidn.com/blogs/BillBrannen/bidn-blog/612/stored-procedure-return-values-and-output-parameters-in-ssis. In your case you need `EXEC ? = pr_procname ?`. Your first parameter is _ReturnValue_. Your second parameter is Input. Start with that

Comment: thanks got worked... I just reversed the order in parameter mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use code that contains two parameter placeholders:

```
EXEC ? = pr_procname ?
```

and in your parameter mapping the *ReturnValue* type parameter comes first